# maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maintainscrollpositionon

How do I maintain the scroll position on a postback in ASP.NET MVC?  The directive maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack on the page and in the web.Config does not seem to apply.

Comment: Postbacks are not part of ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no longer PostBacks in ASP.NET MVC. There's a nice [jquery scrollsaver plugin](http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver) which is worth checking out.

Comment: Tried this with no success.  I will update this once I tackle it.

Comment: Broken link for plugin

Comment: Here is a working solution: https://github.com/evaldsurtans/maintainscroll.jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

Not PostBack-related, but this answer helped me maintain scroll position after form was submitted:
[How do I maintain scroll position in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484463/how-do-i-maintain-scroll-position-in-mvc/6684825#6684825)