# How to maintain scroll in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need help about how we can maintain scroll position in ASP.NET MVC during server calls or postbacks

Comment: Well, you can set an anchor to a position in the page and send the user to that anchor as part of the loading of that page.  But, in general, when a page loads it *should* put the user at the top.  If you want to retain the same page and just update some data on it, you should use AJAX and dynamically change the page content with JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I maintain scroll position in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484463/how-do-i-maintain-scroll-position-in-mvc)

Answer (score 3):

I would certainly agree with Nick Berardi in his answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484463/how-do-i-maintain-scroll-position-in-mvc):-

> Actually there is no standard way of handling this, this was a
>   Microsoft hack to support their post back model. They needed this because every control did a post > > back and the user would constantly be pushed back to the top of the page.