# BeginCollectionItem Maintain Page Position MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to find the best method (any at this point) in which to keep page scroll position when deleting an item from a list using beginCollectionItem.

Initially I thought it was due to my other javascript/jQuery code in my main project (it still could be a factor), but when I recreated the situation in a new project only using the BCI code (index, two partials, controller, and model), when deleting an item from either of the lists, the page would jump to the top again, I really need (want) this to stop, how can I achieve this?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484463/how-do-i-maintain-scroll-position-in-mvc) question and the top answer I don't know how to properly implement or even if it's still valid, the second answer, using the below JS I have tested within my `_Layout`, within the `budles` which didn't fix the issue.

**jQuery test**

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    localStorage['page'] = document.URL;
    localStorage['scrollTop'] = $(document).scrollTop();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage['page'] == document.URL) {
        $(document).scrollTop(localStorage['scrollTop']);
    }
});
```

**Student Partial**

```
@model UsefulCode.Models.Person
<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("students"))
    {
        <div class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <span>
                    <span class="dltBtn">
                        <a href="#" class="deleteRow">X</a>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Teacher Partial**

```
@model UsefulCode.Models.Person
<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("teachers"))
    {
        <div class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <span>
                    <span class="dltBtn">
                        <a href="#" class="deleteRow">X</a>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Index**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model UsefulCode.Models.Register
<div id="studentList">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="editorRowsStudents">
        @foreach (var item in Model.students)
        {
            @Html.Partial("StudentView", item)
        }
    </div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add", "StudentManager", null, new { id = "addItemStudents", @class = "button" });
}
</div>

<div id="teacherList">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="editorRowsTeachers">
        @foreach (var item in Model.teachers)
        {
            @Html.Partial("TeacherView", item)
        }
    </div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add", "TeacherManager", null, new { id = "addItemTeachers", @class = "button" });
}
</div>


@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#addItemStudents').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("StudentManager")',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) { $("#editorRowsStudents").append(html); }
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#editorRowsStudents').on('click', '.deleteRow', function () {
                $(this).closest('.editorRow').remove();
            });
            $('#addItemTeachers').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("TeacherManager")',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) { $("#editorRowsTeachers").append(html); }
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#editorRowsTeachers').on('click', '.deleteRow', function () {
                $(this).closest('.editorRow').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from inflicting pain to myself for how dense I now feel I am relieved.
Adding `return false;` to the delete action resolves this, it was present on the add action but from staring at it for hours I just assumed it was there.

If there is a better answer, please put it in as this will only work on this section of code.

Below is the answer code:

```
$('#addItemStudents').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("StudentManager")',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) { $("#editorRowsStudents").append(html); }
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#editorRowsStudents').on('click', '.deleteRow', function () {
                $(this).closest('.editorRow').remove();
                return false; // add this
            });
```