# Why do `JQuery` tabs lose styling after a button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tabs, postback

I am using `JQuery` tabs in my `Asp.Net/C#` app.

I am modelling my approach after [this article.](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Tabs-Maintain-Selected-Tab-on-PostBack-in-ASPNet.aspx) The `JQuery` is outside of my

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"...></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

wrapper while the html components are inside.

[image]

Whenever I click a button, my tabs completely lose their `CSS` styling and I see all of the tab contents, rather than just the

```
<div id="current-tab">
```

for that tab.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

My guess is that its related to post-back or the update panel somehow, but I am not sure why the added `C#` code under `page_load` doesn't keep the selected tab current on `post-back` when the button is fired.

[image]
**ASPX**

```
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
        var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
            activate: function (e, i) {
                selected_tab = i.index;
            }
        });
        selected_tab = $("[id$=selected_tab]").val() != "" ? parseInt($("[id$=selected_tab]").val()) : 0;
        tabs.tabs('select', selected_tab);
        $("form").submit(function () {
            $("[id$=selected_tab]").val(selected_tab);
        });
        ...
</script>
....
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">                                
      <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#tab-1">Tier 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-2">Tier 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-3">Tier 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab-4">Tier 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab-1">
             ...
            </div>
            <div id="tab-2">
             ...
            </div>
            <div id="tab-3">
             ...
            </div>
            <div id="tab-4">
             ...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="selected_tab" runat="server" />
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**C#**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ...
     selected_tab.Value = Request.Form[selected_tab.UniqueID];
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it has something to do with a Partial PostBack. So in order for jquery functions to work again you need to rebind it after the Partial PostBack is done.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        buildTabs();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        buildTabs();
    });

    function buildTabs() {
        var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
            activate: function (e, i) {
                selected_tab = i.index;
            }
        });
        selected_tab = $("[id$=selected_tab]").val() != "" ? parseInt($("[id$=selected_tab]").val()) : 0;
        tabs.tabs('select', selected_tab);
        $("form").submit(function () {
            $("[id$=selected_tab]").val(selected_tab);
        });
    }
</script>
```

But the selected tab is a different story. You also need to store the active tab somewhere and re-apply it after the partial PostBack is done. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484463/how-do-i-maintain-scroll-position-in-mvc) answer for details.
But basically you need to store the active tab ID in SessionStorage, cookie or Hiddden input and re-apply it in `prm.add_endRequest(function () {`

Comment: This resolved the loss of styling, but in regards to keeping the selected tab open after postback, I have a question. Would the `selected_tab` variable not have the active tab id?

Comment: That could very well be the case. I did not examine the code for creating the actual tabs. But if you can re-apply the tab from that variable it should work.

Comment: Nope, it just returns an index variable of 0. Not sure if that's what is suppose to be returned.

Comment: You can bind a click event to the tabs with jquery that reads the ID. But you need to give them one `<a href="#tab-1" id="ID is Needed">`